# Backbone Marionette Event Aggregator : how to listen at the App level to ItemView Event

Tags: marionette

I'm new to Marionette and can't get my head around events...

I have an ItemView which trigger an event, and I would like to receive this event at the application level, but when my app listen for this event, nothing happens...

If the Event Aggregator is in Application and ItemView, why this code doesn't work ? :

```
var MessageItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#messagesTPL",
  tagName: 'tr',
  className: 'messageItem',
  events : {
    'click': 'displayMessage'
  },
  displayMessage: function () {
    this.trigger('display:message');
  }
});

App.on('display:message', function () {
  console.log('display message !!!');
});
```

Comment: David's answer is the correct way to do what you want but I would caution you against using the global event aggregator if you don't need to. Every `Backbone` object extends `Backbone.Event` and you will be much happier in the long run if you use `listenTo` and keep events as local as possible.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to listen for the event at the application level, you have to trigger it at the application level:

```
displayMessage: function () {
  myApp.trigger('display:message');
}
```

Assuming `myApp` is your Marionette application. Then, you simply listen for that event:

```
myApp.on('display:message', ...)
```

It's the only way to implement what you asked for: "I have an ItemView which trigger an event, and I would like to receive this event at the application level". Depending on your situation, the better way is to either

- use listenTo as Andrew suggested (see an example here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/config/marionette/regions/dialog.js). In the example, the dialog region listens to a "dialog:close" event triggered on the view, and reacts to it
- use a controller to listen to events on the view and react properly, as you can see here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L38 The controller reacts to a "contacts:filter" event that was triggered in the view, and reacts to it

Neither of these 2 solutions requires "polluting" the global event space.

Comment: thanks a lot. things become clearer... But is your answer David the clean way ? I was thinking that the Event Aggregator was a hub for all events between components (views, models, application, ...). Andrew, how would you implement the listenTo on this example ? You say to keep events as local as possible, but I was thinking about my app as a coordinator : you click on an ItemView which is e.g. a new mail, then the application hide the mails list and show the mail's view.

Comment: thank you. I looked at your example code, but when I implement it the callback displayMessage in the Region object is not called (see the code below), and I can't find others example with Google...

Answer (score 2):

ok so I tried the listenTo solution, here is part of my code:

```
var regionManager = Backbone.Marionette.Region.extend({
    el: "#messages",
    onShow: function (view) {
        this.listenTo(view, "display:message", this.displayMessage);
    },
    displayMessage: function () {
        console.log('regionManager received display:message');
    }
});
App.addRegions({
    messageListRegion: regionManager

});
var MessageItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#messagesTPL",
    tagName: 'tr',
    className: 'messageItem',
    events : {
        'click': 'displayMessage'
    },
    displayMessage: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.trigger('display:message');
    }
});
```

But when I click on a messageItemView, the regionManager does not execute the displayMessage callback set in the listenTo method.

Comment: I found the solution... Very, very tricky... listenTo must listen to "itemview:display:message" and not "display:message" cuz the event comes from an itemView, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740793/do-itemview-triggers-bubble-up

Comment: That is very strange... The "itemview" prefix should only be added to a collection/composite view. My example doesn't use the prefix and works fine, including with item views...

Comment: Yes, definitely. This is why jsFiddles are useful: you can see the entire code context :-)