# Do backbone marionette.js parent view bubble down?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I reference this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740793/do-itemview-triggers-bubble-up) and [document](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#childview-event-bubbling-from-child-views) I know how to bubble up.

But in my situation, I want to bubble down.

Just like I click a button on parent view then trigger some function of all my childview.

```
var parent = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    triggers: {
        'click #edit': "??"  // trigger the childview
    }
})
```

above just the code to describe my concept.

**Edit**

Or maybe not use the marionette, can use backbone to do the trick?

Does anyone know how to make it?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Marionette, then you can access all your child views with `this.children`. The `children` property delegates some underscore functions like `invoke`, so you could call `this.children.invoke`. Something like this might work for your needs:

```
var ChildView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: _.template('child'),

  myChildFunction: function() {
    console.log('child view', this);
  }
});

var ParentView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: _.template('<button id="edit">Edit</button><div class="children"></div>'),

  childView: ChildView,

  childViewContainer: '.children',

  events: {
    'click #edit': 'triggerChildren'
  },

  triggerChildren: function() {
    this.children.invoke('myChildFunction');
  }
});
```